# Attempting to do a Restful Service using Java Eclipse. I am getting an Error 404

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat

I am trying to make a Restful service using the below tutorial.  Because I am using Tommee plus, it was my understanding that a web.xml file was not necessary for the file pathing.  In any case, I am getting an error 404 from the tomee plus server.

I am using java jdk 1.8, Tommee plus 8.0, and javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar.  Eclipse 2022.

https://www.theserverside.com/video/Step-by-step-RESTful-web-service-example-in-Java-using-Eclipse

None of the expected paths are working.  I'm not sure why.

```
package com.mcnz.restful.java.example;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/")
public class ScoreService {
    public static int wins, losses, ties;

    @GET
    @Path("/score")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getScore() {
        String pattern = "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"losses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\"}";
        return String.format(pattern,  wins, losses, ties);
    }
    
    //localhost:8080/restful-java/score?wins=2%losses=3@ties=15
    
    @PUT
    @Path("/score")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String updateScore(  @QueryParam("wins")     int wins, 
                                @QueryParam("losses")   int losses, 
                                @QueryParam("ties")     int ties) {
        ScoreService.wins = wins;
        ScoreService.losses = losses;
        ScoreService.ties = ties;
        String pattern = "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"losses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\"}";
        return String.format(pattern,  wins, losses, ties);
        
    }
    
    @POST @Path("/score/wins")@Produces("application/plain")
    public int increaseWins() {
        return ++wins;
    }
    @POST @Path("/score/ties")@Produces("application/plain")
    public int increaseTies() {
        return ++ties;
    }
    @POST @Path("/score/losses")@Produces("application/plain")
    public int increaseLosses() {
        return ++losses;
    }
    @GET @Path("/score/wins")@Produces("application/plain")
    public int getWins() {
        return wins;
    }
    @GET @Path("/score/losses")@Produces("application/plain")
    public int getLosses() {
        return losses;
    }
    @GET @Path("/score/ties")@Produces("application/plain")
    public int getTies() {
        return ties;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What URL are you calling, and what in this source file makes that valid?

Comment: @nitind  so, my understanding is that my base url should be:
http://localhost:8080/restful-java/   Then, I add for example "score" to get:         http://localhost:8080/restful-java/score           OR http://localhost:8080/restful-java/score/wins

Comment: The address/port# pair is from my own system and the server im running, the "restful-java" is the name of the project.  Then, the @Path() tags add to the URL.   The tutorial I'm using stated that Tomee plus was able to handle this method without any XML file.

Comment: Right, but what URL are you actually calling? Not an example, the one that's failing.

Comment: I have called all of  localhost:8080/restful-java/score   ,    localhost:8080/restful-java/score/wins ,  localhost:8080/restful-java/score/ties,  localhost:8080/restful-java/score/losses  .   They all fail.

Comment: What does the log say?